# maintaining vr mode across screens

Tags: aframe

I wish to go from one VR page to the next, while maintaining VR mode. According to the documentation this should be possible, but various attempts I have tried failed to do this. My latest attempt is https://retainingvrmode.glitch.me/. Does anybody have a working example or does anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Keep in mind that In-VR navigation is only supported on Firefox, Oculus Browser, Samsung Internet and Supermedium

Comment: Thank you. It works for me on the oculus go, but not on the mozilla browser on my desktop.

Comment: It works for me on Firefox release channel and Oculus Rift headset.